# How to print xml image in IOS?

Tags: c++, c, ios, ios4

I've created a simple XML-Parser to parse my rss Feeds to my app.
The id, currentstatus, picture of the simple to parse from the xml file.
But I can't get the image from the XML file. . i retrieve the all the images from xml file. but the noimage.jpg not displaying. could you please any help me.

XML code

```
<Agent>
<id>3422</id>
<currentstatus>Logged Off</currentstatus>
<picture>1</picture>
</Agent>
<Agent>
<id>3432</id>
<currentstatus>Logged Off</currentstatus>
<picture>0</picture>
</Agent>
```

i tried the following code:

```
UIImage * cellimages = [[UIImage alloc]init];   
NSString *string1 = @"http://telecomstats.co.uk/images/LLReaderProfile/";
NSString *cellvalue =[[[[self rssParser]rssItems]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]picture];
NSString* disable = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"0"];


if (cellvalue == disable)
{
 cellimages = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:@"http://telecomstats.co.uk/images/LLReaderProfile/noimage.jpg"];
} 
else     {

    cellimages = [string1 stringByAppendingString:[[[[self rssParser]rssItems]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]id]];
    cellimages = [cellimages stringByAppendingString: @".jpg"];  

}

cellimages = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:cellimages]]];  
cell.imageView.image = cellimages;
```

Does someone can help me? 
Thanks for any help and insight.

Comment: Are the URLs correct? At least the noimage URL gives a domain not found.

Comment: Thank You for the replay sorry i enter the wrong URL correct URL is :static.telecomstats.co.uk/images/psychic/LLReaderProfile/… i tried the following Method as well cellimages = [string1 stringByAppendingString: @"noimage.jpg"]; but no use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using `cellimages` which is an `UIImage` object to store strings in your else-branch. Also when `cellvalue == disable` is true, you execute this:

```
cellimages = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:@"http://telecomstats.co.uk/images/LLReaderProfile/noimage.jpg"];
cellimages = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:cellimages]]];
```

There you put an `UIImage` in `[NSURL URLWithString:]` which probably will not work; actually this code should produce quite some warnings. Try to properly separate between the URL string and the image object to display. Put all URL stuff in an `NSString` and get the `UIImage` afterwards when you have determined the correct URL.

Note that your code has some other problems, especially that you are using `dataWithContentsOfURL` and `imageWirhContentsOfFile` both of which will block until the image is retriebes. This will result in application hangs when using a bad internet connection and if the network is too slow, will crash your app. Have a look into asynchronous downloads and using frameworks like AFNetworking.

Comment: Thank you for your kindness. i will try. in my poing of view the if condition is wrong, because the all the readers photos is displaying, but only noimages.jpg not displaying.

Comment: This is because when the condition is true (if-branch) you set `cellimages` to an `UIImage` object. If the else-branch is taken, `cellimages` contains a string which is correctly processed by `NSURL`, which is why all other images are displayed correctly. If you would set `cellimages` to a string in the if-branch as well (i.e. the full URL), it would probably work but using `cellimages` for both, the URL string (type `NSString`) and the image (type `UIImage`) is *very* bad practice.

Comment: i tried like     if ([[[[self rssParser]rssItems]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]picture] == disable)

but no use . is there any way to solve this problem. if you know please tel me the hint. because i am new this field. basically i am a web designer. now i done all the functionality except this one. 

Thank you

Comment: The if part is not the issue, the issue is that you use the same variable for an URL and the image. Create an `NSString *myurl` and put the URL in there, e.g. `myurl = @"http://telecomstats.co.uk/images/LLReaderProfile/noimage.jpg"` and `myurl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://telecomstats.co.uk/images/LLReaderProfile/%@.jpg, [[[[self rssParser]rssItems]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]id]];` in the respective places. Then use `myurl` in your last statement where you construct the image.

Comment: hi thank you for your help i solved this problem. if condition only wrong. correct one is     "if ([cellvalue isEqualToString:@"0"])"
cheers...